# HTML technique to create custom dotted borders on divs?

Tags: html, css, border

Here is a screenshot example:

[image]

Notice the border around the container. How can I achieve this effect for a website?

I've tried the following rule:

```
border: 1px dotted black;
```

And it results in:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `dashed`.

```
border: 1px dashed #ccc;
```

[Example.](http://jsbin.com/arigap)

Answer (score 2):

That is not entirely cross browser compliant as it is new in CSS3. You can read more about it here: http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/

A more custom way to do it would be with two overlapping divs where one is only slightly larger than the other by either size or by using padding.

Comment: You don't need border images to create `border: dashed;`, that's definitely overkill.

Comment: Perhaps, but the question in the headline of the post is how to create a CUSTOM border.

Comment: I was just trying to point out how to use images as a border because it was implied that a custom one was being used. If `border:dashed;` is all you want then simply using that css will work as well.

Answer (score 2):

the size of the dots is controlled by the border-width - try `border: 4px dotted #ccc;`

Answer (score 0):

Set `margin-top` to `0.5em` on the text, and the `border` to `dashed`

See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/n7Ejj/1/)

For the full layout try something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/n7Ejj/2/)